# Pytest not working in VSCODE, after installing the package in venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I'm trying to run pytest which worked in pycharm, but can't manage to run it on vscode.

First I'm doing:

```
python -m venv env
```

```
env\Scripts\activate
```

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

```
pip install selenium webdriver-manager pytest pytest-html
```

```
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
pip                23.3.2
pytest             7.4.4
pytest-html        4.1.1
pytest-metadata    3.0.0
pytest-xdist       3.5.0
selenium           4.16.0
setuptools         69.0.3
webdriver-manager  4.0.1
```

The packages appear in the venv yet getting the following error:

```
(env) PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\automation-projects\Python\paloAlto> pytest
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\automation-projects\Python\paloAlto\env\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 267, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     config._do_configure()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\automation-projects\Python\paloAlto\env\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1053, in _do_configure
INTERNALERROR>     self.hook.pytest_configure.call_historic(kwargs=dict(config=self))
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\automation-projects\Python\paloAlto\env\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 514, in call_historic
INTERNALERROR>     res = self._hookexec(self.name, self._hookimpls, kwargs, False)
INTERNALERROR>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\automation-projects\Python\paloAlto\env\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 115, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\automation-projects\Python\paloAlto\env\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 113, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     raise exception.with_traceback(exception.__traceback__)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\automation-projects\Python\paloAlto\env\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 77, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\automation-projects\Python\paloAlto\testCases\conftest.py", line 49, in pytest_configure
INTERNALERROR>     config._metadata['Project Name'] = 'Palo Alto'
INTERNALERROR>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute '_metadata'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\automation-projects\Python\paloAlto\testCases\conftest.py", line 49, in pytest_configure
INTERNALERROR>     config._metadata['Project Name'] = 'Palo Alto'
```

In pytest, the Config object does not have a `_metadata` attribute by default.

It should be changed to:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addini("metadata", type="args", help="add metadata", default=[])

def pytest_configure(config):
    for name in config.getini("metadata"):
        config._metadata[name] = 'Palo Alto'
```

This should resolve the AttributeError you're seeing.

Comment: getting the same error AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'metadata'

Comment: This means the `metadata` attribute is not directly accessible from the `config` object. I edited my answer, can this help?

Answer (score 0):

`PS` suggests you are using a `Powershell` terminal. Close that terminal and start a `command prompt` terminal. `Powershell` terminal can generate many issues with Python.

Comment: Exactly the same errors with command prompt